# session_start() error on tmpfs: Protocol driver not attached (49)

Tags: php, magento, session, lamp, tmpfs

I have a Redhat Enterprise LAMP server, hosting a Magento site, where I recently set up tmpfs for the session directory to improve performance. The tmpfs partition is mounted with the following command:

```
mount -t tmpfs -o rw,noexec,nosuid,size=6144M,mode=1777,uid=48,gid=48 tmpfs /path/session
```

After mounting the session directory to tmpfs, the following warning is thrown in about 1% of all sessions:

```
 Warning: session_start(): open(/path/session/sess_random_session_id, O_RDWR) failed: Protocol driver not attached (49)  in /path/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 115**
```

I haven't been able to reproduce the error - but it occurs several times daily, according to logs.

I am running `Apache v 2.2.3` and `Magento v 1.4.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

You should use Memcache to store session, files are bad because PHP locks the current user session file during all the PHP execution, and I know Magento has some AJAX queries executed in parallel :/

Also, I believe TMPFS regenerate inode ([how are inode numbers generated in linux tmpfs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411701/how-are-inode-numbers-generated-in-linux-tmpfs)) so it mays cause a problem with sessions.

Comment: How does the file lock + ajax query differ when using memcached rather than tmpfs? The problem occurred while switching to tmpfs.

Comment: Imagine a web site who does 4 AJAX calls after page load, that means 4 new HTTP connections from same session (means also 4 mysql connections etc...), but PHP use file lock to retrieve file session between session_start() and session end or Php exists. Memcache session has not this lock.

Comment: I recommended you memcache because I believed you switch to tmpfs in order to improve performance of session?